# Mongodb-MapReduce Problems with big array

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I hope someone could help with this problem. Thanks!

I'm working in a log parser of MYSQL. I use for this task PHP5.310 to parse the mysql logs and store the information gathered into mongodb as the following structure:

```
        "_id" : "12345",
        "Host" : "localhost",
        "Connect" : "XXXXX@localhost on AUT_IND",
        "Time_Con" : ISODate("2013-01-21T02:50:08Z"),
        "Quit" : "Quit",
        "Time_Quit" : ISODate("2013-01-21T02:50:09Z"),
        "Num_Query" : 2,
        "Query" : [
                "SET NAMES utf8",
                 "SELECT * FROM XX

        ]
```

I'm trying to get a top ten of Queries in the whole collection. I've used this M/R:

```
function emit(k, v) {
print("emit");
print(" k:" + k + " v:" + tojson(v));
}
```

m =

```
function () {
this.Query.forEach(function (z) {emit(z, 1);});
}
```

r=

```
function (key, values) {
var total = 0;
for (var i in values) {
total += values[i];
}
return total;
}

}
```

And the map reduce db.XXXXX.mapReduce(m,r,{out:"results"})  give me the right results except when the Num_queries is higher than 3k.

For example I have one document in this collection with "Num_Query" : 116287.

So It has an array with 116287 Queries. It's here where I got the error when I do M/R.

Here you have the error log:

Fri Feb  8 12:07:00 uncaught exception: map reduce failed:{ "errmsg" : "exception: _id cannot be an array", "code" : 10099, "ok" : 0 }

I hope someone could head me to the right solution. Thanks very much